# numpy.where() also computes unused values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using `numpy.where` to compute the values of a function on different domains.

I am surprised to see that `numpy.where` evaluates [**both provided expressions**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (x and y) for the entire array, **regardless of the condition being satisfied or not**.

It means that when dealing with slow functions, **a lot of time is spent** evaluating something that will not be used in the end.

### Example

```
import time

def f1(x):
    print("f1")
    print(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    return 0

def f2(x):
    print("f2")
    print(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    return 1


a = np.array([-1, 1])
np.where(a<0, f1(a), f2(a))
```

Output :

```
f1
[-1  1]
f2
[-1  1]
```

### Question

Is there a reason for this behaviour ? How do I easily avoid these useless manipulations with numpy ?

### Additional info

Here's an illustration of what I would expect it to do (in pure python) to avoid useless evaluations. Though, I'd prefer a numpy-based solution.

```
a = [-1, 1]
r = []
for x in a:
    if x<0:
        r.append(f1(a))
    else:
        r.append(f2(a))
```

Comment: `np.where` is a Python function.  Python evaluates all function arguments before they are passed to any function.  Conditional or iterative evaluation is not implied by the syntax or the documentation.  `np.where` just sees three arrays as specified by the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of `np.where` and you cannot really overcome it if you stick with this function.

What you can do though is to use a mask:

```py
mask = (a < 0)
d = np.empty_like(a)
d[mask] = f1(a[mask])
d[~mask] = f2(a[~mask])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your:

```
np.where(a<0, f1(a), f2(a))
```

is the same as:

```
In [4]: cond = a<0; x1 = f1(a); x2 = f2(a)
   ...: np.where(cond, x1, x2)
f1
[-1  1]
f2
[-1  1]
Out[4]: array([0, 1])
```

There's not conditional or iterative evaluation implied in the `np.where` function call.

If your `f1` and `f2` only work with scalar inputs (as opposed to arrays as they now do), there isn't much you can do to get around:

```
Out[7]: array([-1,  1])
In [8]: [f1(i) if i<0 else f2(i) for i in a]
f1
-1
f2
1
Out[8]: [0, 1]
```

The other answer suggests masking.  You'll have to do your own timings to see which is fastest.  `numpy` is geared toward working with whole-arrays, even if that means higher memory use or superfluous calculations (by `c` code standards).